# Getting parent-child data into an Oracle level-based OLAP hierarchy

Tags: oracle, parent-child, hierarchy, olap

We have some organisational data which we need to represent in an Oracle OLAP 10g dimension, preferably populated using Warehouse Builder.

The organisational hierarchy is listed as parent-child pairs, and is both ragged (unbalanced) and skip-level (noncovering). This would lend itself to a value-based hierarchy, but our client would rather we use ROLAP rather than MOLAP, i.e. avoid the use of an Analytical Workspace, which rules out the use of a value-based hierarchy.

Is there a straightforward way to populate a level-based hierarchy using parent-child pair data, and if so how can it be done?

Pointers to tutorials would be welcome, especially if they use Warehouse Builder.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a CONNECT BY PRIOR query, you can use PRIOR column_name in the SELECT clause to retrieve the parent column's data.